# Losing session when refresing

Tags: node.js, socket.io, express-session

I'm having a problem with Socket.io. I have a node.js server which utilizes the code from the READ.ME
The socket works fine when I initally create it, but when I refresh the page, the socket on the client side get lost.

Here is the code on my server:

```
'use strict';

const app = require('express')();
const http = require('http').Server(app);
const io = require('socket.io')(http);
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const messageRoutes = require('./routes/messages');
const db = require('./models');
const session = require("express-session")({
    secret: "my-secret",
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: true
});
const sharedsession = require("express-socket.io-session");

app.use(session);
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

io.use(sharedsession(session, {
    autoSave: true
}));
io.on('connection', socket => {
    socket.on("login", function (userdata) {
        socket.handshake.session.userdata = userdata;
        socket.handshake.session.save();

        const { username } = userdata;
        const loggedInMessage = {
            message: `${username} has logged in`
        }

        console.log(loggedInMessage.message);
        socket.broadcast.emit('chat message', loggedInMessage);
    });

    socket.on("logout", function (userdata) {
        if (socket.handshake.session.userdata) {
            console.log(`${socket.handshake.session.userdata.username} has disconnected`);
            delete socket.handshake.session.userdata;
            socket.handshake.session.save();
        }
    });
});

// Setting up Routes
app.use("/api/messages", messageRoutes);

http.listen(3001, () => {
    console.log('Listening on port 3001');
});
```

As you can see, I import the `express-session` and then `express-socket.io-session`. Then I attach the `sharedsession` middleware onto the `io` instance.
Right after, I define my listeners for the login and logout events. When a new user log in, I save his userdata inside my session object and saves it.

The problem is, when I refresh the page, the socket get lost and I can't access the session object on the client side.

How can I solve this?

Comment: Hello, I have same problem. Have you solved this problem?

Comment: I'm afraid not.

Comment: @anna and David: were either of you ever able to resolve this? I'm also struggling to not loose the session data upon browser refresh...